# Best way to weekly update a MYSQL field?

Tags: mysql, architecture, average

I want to weekly update a field in a MySQL table "Persons", with the avg of two fields of the "Tasks" table, end_date and start_date:

```
PERSON:
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| average_speed  | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

TASKS:
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| person_id      | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| start_date     | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| end_date       | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

(tables are not complete).

average_speed = AVG(task.end_date - task.start_date)

Now, the Tasks table is really big, and ** I don't want to compute the average on every task for every person every week**. (That's a solution, but I'm trying to avoid it).

What's the best way to update the average_speed? 
I thought about adding two columns in the person's table:

- "last_count": count of computed tasks since now for each person
- "last_sum": last sum of (end_date - start_date) for each person

So that on a new update i could do something like average_speed = (last_sum+new_sum) / (last_count + new_count) where new_count is the sum of the tasks in the last week.

**Is there a better solution/architecture?**

EDIT:
to answer a comment, the query I would do is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    count(t.id) as last_count,
    sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.start_date, t.end_date)) as last_sum
    avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.start_date, t.end_date))
from tasks as t
where t.end_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND CURDATE()
```

And i can rely on a php script to get result and do some calculations

Comment: do you have an sample queries for that problem?

Comment: do you have an error ?

Comment: The best way is possibly not to store this at all, but instead calculate it as and when required.

Comment: @Strawberry problem is that the tasks table has near 1 million rows with a total of more than 7 GB of data, calculate it every time is required (and considering all tasks) is sooo slow. And it's a query that will be fired 100s of times a day.

Comment: @Jervz09 no, no errors, but I honestly don't like my solution, I was searching for a better one, some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a periodic update to the table is a bad way to go for all the reasons you've listed above, and others.

If you have access to the code that writes to the Tasks table, that’s the best place to put the update.  Add an Average field and calculate and set the value when you write the task end time.

If you don’t have access to the code, you can add a calculated field to the table that shows the average and let SQL figure it out during the execution of a query.  This can slow queries down a little, but the data is always valid and SQL is smart enough to only calculate that value when it is needed.

A third (ugly) option is a trigger on the table that updates the value when appropriate.  I’m not a fan of triggers because they hide business logic in unexpected places, but sometimes you just have to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you're right all the way, but the things I can do are very limited. I will take into consideration your first option. But sticking to this ugly update i tried to explain, you think there's a better solution?

Comment: If you have to do that update, then there is no better way to do it.  If you have access to the DB you can create a separate summary table and keep the values in there.  Then you just insert into the summary table "where {id} not in {main table}".  That should be faster.